# How to get all products and its attributes?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products

I want to fetch all products in my ecommerce and all its attributes. How can I do that? 
For example, I want to be able to call a function that gets all products, an then one by one fetch all the attributes of that product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code for your requirement.

```
<?php
namespace Test\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection;
}
}
?>
```

Display in phtml using block method

`$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());

    echo "<br>";
}`

Comment: What if I want to fetch also all attributes that are not in the default attribute set? Will this work too?

Comment: Yes. It will fetch all attributes